# How to set navigation drawer menuitem checked from within a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigationview, android-drawer

I have an AppCompatActivity with DrawerLayout and a NavigationView. I can start three different fragments from the NavigationView.

I want to show the checked status in the navigation drawer according to the fragment I am in.

It works fine, when navigating through the navigation drawer. But I don't know, how to achieve that also with the back button.

Probably I need to use something like

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

but how do I get ahold of the NavigationView from within the fragment?

Or, other way around, I would need to handle that in the main activity. Then I must need to know, which fragment is active at the moment.

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to change current navigation drawer selected item via back button and using addToBackStack(true) function. IMHO, it`s bad idea. If you placed navigation drawer, all your navigation must be through the navigation drawer, not through the back buttom or through another fragment.